# Mutating state values in useEffect isn't working (react 16+, react-router v6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to fetch a url when the page first loads and when the location changes. The first load works fine. The record id is pulled from params and when that changes, useEffect gets called again to reset state and reload the new records. However, all of the set* calls in useEffect aren't doing anything as the loadData() method sees the old data still `(hasMoreData=false, dataRecords=[...])`.

```js
export function MyComponent(props) {
  const [hasMoreData, setHasMoreData] = useState(true);
  const [dataRecords, setDataRecords] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const params = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const { id } = params;

  const loadData = useCallback((page = 1) => {
    if (hasMoreData) {
      fetchSomeData(`api/records?id=${id}&page=${page}`).then((response) => {
        const { data } = response;
        // note: pagination logic omitted for clarity
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          setDataRecords(data);
        } else {
          setHasMoreData(false);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [id, dataRecords, hasMoreData]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // id param has changed, or its the first load - reset all fields, then fetch new data
    setHasMoreData(true);
    setDataRecords([]);
    setCurrentPage(1);
    loadData(currentPage);
  }, [location]);

  // ...currentPage managed via infiniteScroll
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What old data is `loadData` seeing? Can you be more specific?

Comment: fetch is a wrapper that handles most of that stuff and not relevant. Assume fetch returns data.

Comment: @DrewReese I thought I had distilled it to something simple, but basically there are several pages of data and when the id param changes I need to clear out the previous data and fetch again. However hasMoreData doesn't get set back to true and dataRecords still contains the data from previous fetches despite it being reset in useEffect().

Comment: You are ***enqueueing*** a state update in the `useEffect` hook. React state updates are asynchronously processed. You will still see the state values from the current render cycle when `loadData` is called.

Comment: @MichaelBrown so you're _not_ using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: You have a **typo**... `page={page}` should be `page=${page}` (you can even see the syntax highlighting change). FYI this is not a practical use for `useCallback`.

Comment: @Phil yes it uses the fetchApi within the wrapper, which decomposes the json response and handles JWT authentication details. Thanks for catching the typo - why is it not a practical use for useCallback()? It was the suggested mechanism for code-reuse right in the docs.

Comment: @MichaelBrown you really only need `useCallback` if you're passing the function to a child component and want to avoid re-renders. See [When to use React.useCallback()](https://aheadcreative.co.uk/articles/when-to-use-react-usecallback/). Regarding `fetch()`, your original question used it directly but now you're using `fetchSomeData()`. Does the latter resolve `response.json()` into a `data` property?

Comment: I think @DrewReese just hit on the correct issue, since they are async I'm not seeing the state updates when loadData is called. I'm not quite sure what the correct way to handle this is, as the whole example was the result of a bunch of different suggestions accepted on SO. At least this gives me a starting point on implementing it properly

Comment: @Phil yes, I have no issues with the fetchSomeData wrapper itself, it correctly handles responses and errors asynchronously. There's a lot going on in the actual implementation hence the simple example. I had updated the example to make it clear I wasn't actually calling the fetch api directly.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `useCallback` at all, you could probably just convert it to an `useEffect` with the same dependencies and move the `loadData` call into it.

Comment: @DrewReese the loadData method is also called by the infinite scroll pagination on the page to load subsequent pages of data, and not just on page load. That's why it was done this way, for code-reuse of that method which seemed to be the suggested way of going about that. Perhaps I should go back to that and see if I can make it work just based on useEffect() with a dependency on the currentPage value.

Answer (score 1):

Comments on the original question lead me to a better way to achieve what I was after. I needed to detect a location change, pagination changes and loading data on initial page load and useCallback wasn't the best way to go about this because the state changes are asynchronous and it didn't see the new values yet. Instead I used a separate `useEffect()` for changes to the `location` so I can reset the internal state data, and a second `useEffect()` to handle changes to `currentPage` rather than calling loadData() directly.

```js
export function MyComponent(props) {
  const [hasMoreData, setHasMoreData] = useState(true);
  const [dataRecords, setDataRecords] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const params = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const { id } = params;

  useEffect(() => {
    // location changed, reset all data
    setHasMoreData(true);
    setDataRecords([]);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  }, [location]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // id param has changed, or its the first load - reset all fields, then fetch new data
    loadData(currentPage);

    function loadData(page = 1) {
      if (hasMoreData) {
        fetchSomeData(`api/records?id=${id}&page=${page}`).then((response) => {
          const { data } = response;
          // note: pagination logic omitted for clarity
          if (data && data.length > 0) {
            setDataRecords(data);
          } else {
            setHasMoreData(false);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }, [currentPage]);

  // ...currentPage managed via infiniteScroll
};
```

Comment: I should note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) helped me end on this solution.